# MDBReact table change labels locale

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap, mdbreact

Is it possible to change MDBReact Table texts such as "Show entries" into Spanish?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do :

```
<MDBDataTable infoLabel={["Afficher", "à", "de", "éléments"]} searchLabel="chercher"/>
```

by overriding

```
<MDBDataTable infoLabel={["Showing", "to", "of", "entries"]} />
```